# Getting access to the non-static field of type array without creating instance of it's class

Tags: java, arrays, field, instance, non-static

while writing some simple game I realised I 've got some trouble to face. I have two separate classes: SettingPanel and Ship. The array of type Class Tile cannot be static because i need two different instances of class SettingPanel. So i need two diffrent arrays aswell.

```
public Class Ship
{
   public Ship()
   {
       SettingPanel.method(?????)
   }
}

public Class SettingPanel
{
   Tile [][] map = new Tile[10][10];
   public SettingPanel(){}
   public static boolean method(Tile[][])
}
```

How can i put the argument(??????) while trying to perform a static method but i do not have an instance of a class SettingPanel and i do not want to. SIngleton? GetComponent()? I need some correct code here. It drives me crazy because it's solution seems to be as easy as abc... Help !

Comment: The problem is i do not know how to get acces to this array from the Ship Class without creating an object of SettingPanel Class.

Comment: By definition, a non-static field exists only as part of an instance.

Comment: I don't see any purpose of passing Tile array to SettingPanel as settingPanel already have the instance.

Comment: SO is there any way to write something like SettingPanel.class or getClass or anything similar?

Comment: ok, finally I solved it by setting SettingPanel as a parent of ship and map Class which holdes the array of Tiles. Now each time i want to get acces from ship to map or opposite I just do it by calling my parent. question.close() :)